# Accessing components of another class

Tags: java, awt, jbutton, jtextarea

Second class:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e.getSource() == buy) {  
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

I want to access the JTextArea from another class and append it with "hi".
so here's what will happen everytime I press the buy button the text area in the another class will append "hi"

Tried solutions:

Second class

```
public void somelistener(ccp asd){
    this.asd = asd;
    this.area = asd.getTextArea();
    area.setText("hi");
}
```

First class

```
public JTextArea getTextArea(){
    return ta;
}
```

Every time I press the button, nothing shows in the textarea.

Comment: I think you mean `area.setText(area.getText() + "hi");`

Comment: still doesnt work </3

Answer (score 0):

you can use nested classes with a tweak to solve your problem. You have to set the JTextArea component an instance variable of the main class. So the the second class (with actionListener) can access the variable. If you created the JTextArea inside the constructor access to it is restricted.
eg:-

```
Public SomeClass{
   private JTextArea txtArea;  // declaring the object here makes it
                                 accessible from nested classes 

   SomeClass(){
       txtArea = new JTextArea(); // initialization of the object
    }
  class Listener(Event evt)
   {
        //Now you xcan use your method :)
   }
```

}

Edit:-

ok here is an another example.

```
Public class MyPanel extends JPanel{

 private JButton btnOK;             //declaring JButton and JTextArea as member 
                                    // variables of class MyPanel
 private JTextArea txtArea ;


   MyPanel(){                    //constructor
      setBackground(Color.RED);
      btnOK = new JButton("OK");          // initializing JButton and JTextArea
      txtArea = new JTextArea("HEllo");
      NestedListener mylistener = new NestedListener();  //creating a listener
      btnOK.addActionListener(mylistener);    // adding the listener to the button
      add(btnOK);
      add(txtArea);
   }
   NestedListener implements ActionListener{    //Nested listener class
                                                //which means it is within 
                                                //the curly brackets of the 
                                                 //first class           
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

          String text = txtArea.getText();    //txtArea is directly accessible here
          txtArea.setText(text + " Again");
     }

  }
```

}

Comment: can you please explain it further with more sample code?